# Let $p$ be an odd prime number. Find the remainder when $(p − 1)!$ is divided by $2p$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I know that by Wilson's theorem $(p-1)! \equiv-1\pmod{p}$, but I can't think of a way transform this into division by $2p$.

Comment: $(p-1)!$ is even or odd?

Comment: Have you tried computing any examples?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

$$(p-1)! \equiv -1 \equiv p-1 \pmod{p}\\
(p-1)! \equiv p-1 \pmod{2}\\$$

Comment: if p is an odd prime ( >2), wouldn't it mean that (p−1)! ≡ 0(mod 2)? because for any n > 1 n! is even?

Comment: @JohnShanks and what is $p-1 \equiv ?? \pmod{2}$?

Comment: p is odd so it has to be 0 right?

Comment: @JohnShanks Yes. And then, if two numbers are congruent to $0 \pmod{2}$, they must also be congruent .....

Answer (score 0):

$$p=2n+1$$

$$(p-1)! = (2n)!$$

$$(2n)!\equiv x\pmod{(2n+1)\cdot 2}$$

$$(p -1)!\equiv x\pmod{2p}$$

Hint:

$$x=p-1$$

Comment: The thing is, I actually tried thinking this way, but could not figure out how to conclude that x is p-1.